# How to set printer margin in java

Tags: java, printing

when trying to print using the Print API - the margins seem to be something not in our control!.. Please help me out to set printer margins or is there any way to set margins at Operating system level.

By default all the four left, right, top and bottom are set to 1.

Answer (score 8):

> **I'm using the Java Printing API, but have problems setting print margins.**
>
> ...
>
> **Solution**
>
> I had to provide additional print attributes to override the default
>   print margins,
>   [MediaPrintableArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaPrintableArea.html).
>
> Most printers cannot print on the entire surface of the media, due to
>   printer hardware limitations.
>
> [MediaPrintableArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaPrintableArea.html)
>   can be used to query the acceptable values for a supposed print job,
>   and to request an area within the constraints of the printable area to
>   be used in a print job.
>
> ```
> HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
> attr.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0f, 0f, w/72f, h/72f, MediaPrintableArea.INCH));       
> PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();    
> job.setPrintService(ps);
> job.setPrintable(this);
> job.setJobName(jobName);
> job.print(attr);
> j.setVisible(false);
> j.dispose();
> ```
>
> The key was to provide the attributes along with the `print()`
>   command.

Source [Help with print margins](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2355563?tstart=0)

Comment: The source is not available anymore. Can someone explain what are the 4 numbers to pass in the constructor of `MediaPrintableArea` ? And what `w` & `h` refer here ?

Comment: @MHogge [MediaPrintableArea (Java Platform SE 7 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaPrintableArea.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
PageFormat defaultPF = printJob.defaultPage();
Paper paper = defaultPF.getPaper();
if (isPortrait)
{
    defaultPF.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, defaultPF.getWidth(), defaultPF.getHeight());
}
else
{
    defaultPF.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, defaultPF.getHeight(), defaultPF.getWidth());
}
defaultPF.setPaper(paper);
defaultPF = printJob.validatePage(defaultPF);

// now dialog has margins set to minimum
PageFormat pf = printJob.pageDialog(defaultPF);
```