# PDFBOX 2 Printed PDF unexpectedly rotated 90

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

Hello I'm tring to print directly a PDF file using PDFBox 2, but if I print the file using pdfbox this is printed rotated by 90°
I have the same issue using an A4 standard printer and also a label printer.
If I try to print using Adobe Reader the same pdf file is printed correctly.

I'm using this code:

```
static void printPDF(String completeFileName, String printerName) {

    try {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream(completeFileName));  //read pdf file.

        javax.print.PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
        DocPrintJob docPrintJob = null;

        int count = service.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (service[i].getName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(printerName)) {
                docPrintJob = service[i].createPrintJob();
                i = count;
            }
        }//for

        PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        pjob.setPrintService(docPrintJob.getPrintService());

        pjob.setJobName("job");

        PDFPageable pAble =  new PDFPageable(doc);
        pjob.setPageable(pAble);
        //pjob.printDialog();
        pjob.print();

    } catch (Exception  er) {
        er.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I don't know where I made the error... I don't find how disable autorotate (in pdfbox v2).

Best regards
Fabio

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using (hopefully 2.0.5), and what size is your PDF (is it a label)? Can you share it? Btw PDFPageable has several constructors. Try the others. Nevertheless, label printing is a known problem (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3117)... maybe we can help you.

Comment: Hello I'm using PDFBox  2.0.5 version, the size of the label is 80x30 mm
Using the contructor
    PDFPageable pAble =  new PDFPageable(doc, Orientation.PORTRAIT);
The label is printed horizzontally but is truncated... problably I have to set the page size ?

Comment: The page size (call `PDPage.setMediaBox()`) must be set, 1 unit = 1/72 inches, 1 inch = 2.54 cm.

Comment: How can I set the margin to 0 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283110/how-to-set-printer-margin-in-java