# Page formating not working for printing a page using Java in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am trying to print a page with custom size. But its not working.
I have made variable for width and height I want my page to be.

See my code ones and suggest some changes

```
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setJobName("Print Data");
        
    job.setPrintable(new Printable(){
        public int print(Graphics pg,PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
            //Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
            Paper paper = new Paper();
            double width = 8d * 22d;
            double height = 4d * 22d;
            double margin = 0.2d * 22d;
            paper.setSize(width, height);
            paper.setImageableArea(
                    margin,
                    margin,
                    width - (margin * 2),
                    height - (margin * 2));
            job.setPrintable(this, pf);
            
            if(pageNum > 0){
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }
            
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)pg;

            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
            
            System.out.println("width1 = " + pf.getWidth());
            System.out.println("height1 = " + pf.getHeight());

            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, pf.getWidth(), pf.getHeight()));

            
            jPanel3.printAll(g2);
     
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS; 
        }
    });
    
    System.out.println("1");
    boolean ok = job.printDialog();
    
    if(ok){
        try{
            System.out.println("2");
            job.print();
            System.out.println("3");
        }
        catch (PrinterException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am stuck at this problem. Whatever size I set. I get print in ISO A4 size. I think their's some mistake with my code.

Comment: Oh, printing, what fun . Okay, the printing API works at a basic level of 72dpi.  So if you want to set the paper size to 10x10 cm, you're going to need to convert that to pixels based on 72dpi for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803741/printing-in-java-to-label-printer/11805237#11805237) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147662/changing-print-margins-on-jtextpane/47148096#47148096) (it's been a long time since I needed to worry about this so it might have changed)

Comment: Okay, also don't try changing the paper inside the `print` method ... kind of to later as the page format and paper details have already been established and the details have probably already been sent to the printer

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of possible issues, but I'm going to address the big glary one

This...

```
job.setPrintable(new Printable(){
    public int print(Graphics pg,PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
        //Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
        Paper paper = new Paper();
        double width = 8d * 22d;
        double height = 4d * 22d;
        double margin = 0.2d * 22d;
        paper.setSize(width, height);
        paper.setImageableArea(
                margin,
                margin,
                width - (margin * 2),
                height - (margin * 2));
        job.setPrintable(this, pf);
```

is a horrible, horrible idea.  Just like when you're painting a component, you don't modify the state, it can have unexpected consequences.

Instead, in this case, you should establish the `Paper` size ahead of time.  This should then be applied to a `PageFormat` and passed to the `PrintJob` via the `setPrintable(Printable, PageFormat)` method.

That means, it might look something more like...

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setJobName("Print Data");
//Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
PageFormat pageFormat = job.defaultPage();
Paper paper = new Paper();
double width = 8d * 22d;
double height = 4d * 22d;
double margin = 0.2d * 22d;
paper.setSize(width, height);
paper.setImageableArea(
        margin,
        margin,
        width - (margin * 2),
        height - (margin * 2));

pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

job.setPrintable(new Printable() {
    @Override
    public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {
        if (pageNum > 0) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;

        g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        System.out.println("width1 = " + pf.getWidth());
        System.out.println("height1 = " + pf.getHeight());

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // Consider using pf.getImageableWidth() and pf.getImageableHeight() instead
        g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, pf.getWidth(), pf.getHeight()));

        // Maybe consider drawing your border first, as `printAll` 
        // might fill in the whole page
        jPanel3.printAll(g2);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}, pageFormat);

System.out.println("1");
boolean ok = job.printDialog();

if (ok) {
    try {
        System.out.println("2");
        job.print();
        System.out.println("3");
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I say might, as there's a bunch of validation and other system junk which might still have it end up not been exactly what you want.

I do suggest having a look at ...

- [Printing in Java to Label Printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803741/printing-in-java-to-label-printer/11805237#11805237)
- [Changing print margins on JTextPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147662/changing-print-margins-on-jtextpane/47148096#47148096)
- [fitting PrinterJob Object to specific print format of BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725456/fitting-printerjob-object-to-specific-print-format-of-bufferedimage/14726386#14726386)
- [How to design an image in java to be printed on a 300 dpi printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975595/how-to-design-an-image-in-java-to-be-printed-on-a-300-dpi-printer/18975822#18975822)
- [java PrinterJob not printing to fit paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27029166/java-printerjob-not-printing-to-fit-paper/27029220#27029220)
- [How can I print a custom paper size (cheques 8" x 4")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558152/how-can-i-print-a-custom-paper-size-cheques-8-x-4/13558335#13558335)
- [Printing a 1800 x 1200 image on 4 x 6 paper using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273402/printing-a-1800-x-1200-image-on-4-x-6-paper-using-java/27356904#27356904)

as some basic examples, all doing similar things - changing the paper size :D

Comment: Can You give me a program with which I can print my image with specific page format. I converted the jPanel to buffered image and then save it in png form and loaded it in Image class. Now I want this image to be printed with particular size and aspect ratio on print page

Comment: BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(jPanel3.getWidth(),jPanel3.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        jPanel3.paint(img.getGraphics());
        try {
            ImageIO.write(img,"png",new File("saved.png"));
            Image image  = ImageIO.read(new File("saved.png"));
          } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(generate_id_card.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

Comment: @AnmolDhall Regarding _"Can You give me a program with which I can print my image with specific page format"_, the answer is no. Please note that this is a site which assists developers with their programming problems, but it is not appropriate to ask others to write your code for you.

Comment: @AnmolDhall There's at least two linked examples which deal with printing images and almost all the linked examples which change the page size/page format

Comment: @AnmolDhall And now you have an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000888/how-to-print-whole-jpanel-with-a-footer-in-every-page-in-java-swing/32001433#32001433) which even deals with multiple page printing